# jQuery capture all changes to named input on a form

Tags: javascript, events, jquery

I'm trying to determine when any of a set of named input/select/radio/checked/hidden fields  in a form change.

In particular, I'd like to capture when any changes are made to fields matching jQuery's selector `$("form :input")`, and where that input is has a `name` attribute. However, the form isn't static i.e. some of the fields are dynamically added later.

My initial thought is to keep track of when new named elements matching  `:input` are added, and then add an event handler, like this:

```
function on_change() {
   alert("The form element with name " + $(this).attr("name") + " has changed");
}

function reg_new_e_handler(input_element) {
    input_element.change(on_change);
}
```

However, I'm quite hopeful I can avoid this with some jQuery magic. In particular, is there a way to register an event handler in jQuery that would handle input elements that match the following:

```
$("form :input").filter( function () { $(this).attr("name") } ).change(on_change);
```

However, have this event set update whenever new input elements are added.

I've thought that it may be possible to capture `keyup` event on the `form` node with `$("form").keyup(on_change)`, but I'm not so sure how one could capture `change` events.

I'd also like this to capture `keyup` events.

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`live` events](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
For example:

```
$(':input[name="something"]'.live('change', function(e) {
    //Do things
});
```

Adding an event handler using `.live` will handle the event for all elements that match the selector, no matter when they were added.

Comment: You could just do :input[name] to get all named elements.

Comment: Yes, `$(':input[name]').live('change onkeyup', foo);` works as expected. That's wickedly cool!